# multilevel inheritance without calling superclass constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I have created three class: Square, Rectangle and Polygon. Square is inheriting from Rectangle and Rectangle is inheriting from Polygon.

The problem is that whenever I call Square constructor, Rectangle constructor get called and I get an error. How can I solve this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Multilevel Inheritance

class Polygon
{
protected:
    int sides;
};

class Rectangle: public Polygon
{
protected:
    int length, breadth;
public:
    Rectangle(int l, int b)
    {
        length = l;
        breadth = b;
        sides = 2;
    }
    void getDimensions()
    {
        cout << "Length = " << length << endl;
        cout << "Breadth = " << breadth << endl;
    }

};

class Square: public Rectangle
{
public:
    Square(int side)
    {
        length = side;
        breadth = length;
        sides = 1;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Square s(10);
    s.getDimensions();
}
```

If I comment out the Rectangle constructor, everything works fine. But I want to have both constructors. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: `class Square: public Rectangle` oh well...

Comment: You don't call the Rectangle constructor directly so the default constructor will be called... however, it doesn't have a default constructor, you have to define it or directly call yours.

Comment: Square/rectangle is actually discussed elsewhere as an example against inheritance. One could be tempted to inverse the inheritance relation, which leads to other problems as well. That said, call Rectangles ctor with side, side: `Square(int side): Rectangle(side,side) {...}` Oh, and Petr has a point in his answer concerning Square's ctor.

Comment: @Meikon How can I directly call my constructor?

Comment: Square(int side): Rectangle(side, side)
{
//other codes
}

Comment: Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem for the semantic mess. Maybe that was why @SingerOfTheFall was sighing?

Comment: @Peter, yes, but that was just a side note, since it is irrelevant to the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not set members of a base class in a derived class constructor. Instead, call the base class constructor explicitly:

```
class Polygon
{
protected:
    int sides;
public:
    Polygon(int _sides): sides(_sides) {} // constructor initializer list!
};

class Rectangle: public Polygon
{
protected:
    int length, breadth;
public:
    Rectangle(int l, int b) :
         Polygon(2), // base class constructor
         length(l),
         breadth(b)
    {}
};

class Square: public Rectangle
{
public:
    Square(int side) : Rectangle(side, side)
    {
        // maybe you need to do this, but this is a sign of a bad design:
        sides = 1;
    }
};
```

Comment: So, should I use Polygon(1) inplace where you have used 'sides = 1'?

Comment: @Lokesh, no, you can call only a constructor of a _direct_ base class, in this case, of a `Rectangle`. You can not call a `Polygon` constructor directly from a `Square` constructor. However, your handling of `sides` smells to me as a bad design: if your `Square` is a subclass of `Rectangle`, then you say that `Square` [is a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `Rectangle`. As such, I would expect that most of properties that hold for `Rectangle` also hold for `Square`. One of such properties seems to be that `sides == 2`, so I would expect `Square` to have `sides==2` too. (cont.)

Comment: ...Actually, there definitely can be situations when your `Rectangle` and `Square` will have different `sides`, but given only the code in question, it is difficult to suggest a particular solution. You might want to ask a separate question for this. Explain what you are trying to achieve, in particular (but not only!) why you need different `sides` for `Rectangle` and `Square`, and probably you will be advised on a better desing.

Comment: ..and one of the solutions based only on the code given is shown in my answer: just set `sides` explicitly in `Square`'s constructor.

Comment: Yep, I agree it's a bad design. I will change it. Anyway I understood how to get around that error.

Answer (score 2):

constructor should be

```
Square(int side) : Rectangle(side, side) { sides = 1; }
```

as `Rectangle` has no default constructor.

Comment: I have never seen this syntax. What does " : " do here?

Comment: It's the initializer list for the members of the class.

Comment: Often it doesn't matter much whether you initialize members this way or by explicit assignment inside the ctor's code, although initialization is cleaner and potentially more efficient. But exactly in cases where you cannot default-initialize the base class (your case) or members -- think references! -- you *need* initialization.